# What does a hash without a key mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What does the {TOKEN} and {ACCOUNT_ID} mean in the following Ruby?

```
my_function({
  :amount => 2000,
  :currency => "usd",
  :source => {TOKEN},
  :destination => {ACCOUNT_ID}
})
```

I have Ruby 2.3.1 and am getting an error `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => (SyntaxError)`

Comment: Ruby hash values must be primitive types. `{TOKEN}` and `{ACCOUNT_ID}` appear to be placeholders for you to edit and replace with your own.

Comment: @bejado : It's the first time I ever see primitive types mentioned with Ruby. What did you mean?

Comment: @EricDuminil: There is no such thing as a primitive type in Ruby. And there is no restriction on hash values. *Any* object can be used as a hash value. Technically, there is a restriction on hash *keys*, since hash keys need to respond to `eql?` and `hash`. But, since both of those methods have default implementations in `Object`, which (almost) all objects inherit, all objects can be used as hash keys as well, although if they don't override `hash` and `eql?` the semantics may be surprising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hash needs to be defined as either empty or with key, value pairs ([see here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html)). I'm guessing if you are following some sort of a tutorial, you need to fill those values in with some constants.

Usually variables in CAPS are constants, but it is possible to define a method in caps. Even so, one would need to call it explicitly with braces, as in `TOKEN()` and I can't think of anything that could be put inside curly braces to initialize a hash of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to end up with a structure like this:

```
my_function({
  :amount => 2000,
  :currency => "usd",
  :source => "THE TOKEN",
  :destination => "THE ACCOUNT ID"
})
```

or

```
my_function({
  :amount => 2000,
  :currency => "usd",
  :source => "ckjnsdncc98n9dnx93d372n",
  :destination => 123456
})
```

The {X} syntax looks like it's used as a placeholder for either Strings or numbers (most likely Strings)